# (Vue.js) In computed, I can't use data

Tags: vue.js

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      test: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    test2: {
      get: () => {
        return console.log(this.test)
      },
      set: () => {
        console.log(this.test)
      }
  }
}
```

But the Error occurred 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined`

I want to use data in computed. but I can't
Help Me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be using arrow functions in the getter and setters, because that [refers to the lexical this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#computed):

> Note that if you use an arrow function with a computed property, `this` won’t be the component’s instance

So, update your code:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      test: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    test2: {
      get: function () {
        return console.log(this.test)
      },
      set: function () {
        console.log(this.test)
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow. I did not know this. I need to read documentation more often. Thanks @Terry

Answer (score 0):

this here refers to the function not vue instance ,you can make this:

```
test2: {
let This = this
      get: () => {
        return console.log(This.test)
      },
      set: () => {
        console.log(This.test)
      }
  }
```